# Surround a pattern, not changing it, while searching for it case-insensitively

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, replace, case-sensitivity

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I haven't found anything so far.

Here's the thing: I have a string and a pattern, and want to surround the pattern inside the string with brackets.

While I want to surround the pattern regardless if it has been matched case-sensitively or not, I want to have it in the same case as it was in the original string.

Here's my best try so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING="ABCBD"
PATTERN="b"

echo $STRING | sed "s/$PATTERN/[$PATTERN]/Ig"
```

The output for this is `A[b]C[b]D`. However, I would like it to be `A[B]C[B]D`.

If the pattern was `B` instead of `b`, the output should also be `A[B]C[B]D`.

If the string was `abcbd` instead of `ABCBD`, the output should be `a[b]c[b]d` for both patterns `B` or `b`.

Do you know any tricks to achieve this? I am glad for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `sed` as well.

```
echo $STRING | sed -e "s/\($PATTERN\)/[\1]/Ig"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind Perl, it's:

```
echo $STRING | perl -pe "s/($PATTERN)/[\1]/ig"
```